# Use Mockito to register spring bean when doing mockMvc testing

Tags: spring, mockito, functional-testing

Here is my idea, I try to test my Restful controller with MockMvc

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
mockMvc.perform(post(...).param(..))
       .andExpect(...);
```

The API I call fires a rabbitmq message. But I don't want to test Amqp in the test. Instead, I create a mock producer like this:

```
@Mock
private AmqpProducer producer
```

I want to inject this producer into the spring context, so I can capture the method call `producer.sendMessage` and test the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mock a bean in the Spring Boot contexte you cannot use directly `@Mock`.
It will create a mock for `AmqpProducer` but not which used by your container.
With Spring, the classical way to do that is annotating your test class with a specific context configuration class or file (`@ContextConfiguration(...)`) that provides the mock.
With Spring Boot, it is simpler : annotating your class with `@WebMvcTest`
and your field to mock with `@MockBean` is enough to mock the bean in the container ([Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)).

Note that `@WebMvcTest` with a specified controller class specified in the annotation value will instantiate the specified controller and also all its direct dependencies declared. So you should mock all of them and not only which one that interests you in your unit test.

So it should look like :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class WebMockTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AmqpProducer producer;

    @Test
    public void foo() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(...);
        verify(producer).sendMessage(expected);

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only cause Spring to create the Web Layer and MyController. No other application beans will be created unless you specify them explicitly.

Comment: I ended up sticking to `MockMvcBuilders`. But the `@MockBean` is a killer.